# RSpec. Using `double` in class methods tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

Maybe, there will be too many code, but I want to understand why RSpec works in this way.
I am trying to `double` external object, that interacts with remote REST API.

Example code:

```rb
class App

  class << self
    def foo
      external.func1
    end

    def bar
      external.func2
    end

    def external
      @external ||= ExternalObject.new
    end
  end

end

class ExternalObject
  def func1
    puts 'func1'
  end

  def func2
    puts 'func2'
  end
end
```

This spec works:

```rb
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'app'

describe App do

  describe '.foo' do
    it 'calls func1' do
      expect_any_instance_of(ExternalObject).to receive(:func1)

      described_class.foo
    end
  end

  describe '.bar' do
    it 'calls func2' do
      expect_any_instance_of(ExternalObject).to receive(:func2)

      described_class.bar
    end
  end

end
```

But this doesn't work:

```rb
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'app'

describe App do

  let(:external) { double('ExternalObject', func1: 1, func2: 2) }
  before(:each) do
    allow(ExternalObject).to receive(:new).and_return(external)
  end

  describe '.foo' do
    it 'calls func1' do
      expect(external).to receive(:func1)

      described_class.foo
    end
  end

  describe '.bar' do
    it 'calls func2' do
      expect(external).to receive(:func2)

      described_class.bar
    end
  end

end
```

RSpec output looks, like `double` doesn't contain stubs anymore, when execute second example:

```rb
1) App.bar calls func2
     Failure/Error: described_class.bar
       Double "ExternalObject" received unexpected message :func2 with (no args)
```

If replace code in `App.external` to this:

```rb
@external = ExternalObject.new
```

everything works well.

I searched for reasons of that error, but haven't found anything.

**UPDATE**

Also, for prevent memoization of the class it's possible to clone object. Maybe it's not a good idea, but it works.

```rb
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'app'

describe App do

  let(:external) { double('ExternalObject', func1: 1, func2: 2) }
  before(:each) do
    stub_const('App', App.clone)
    allow(ExternalObject).to receive(:new).and_return(external)
  end

  describe '.foo' do
    it 'calls func1' do
      expect(external).to receive(:func1)

      App.foo
    end
  end

  describe '.bar' do
    it 'calls func2' do
      expect(external).to receive(:func2)

      App.bar
    end
  end

end
```

**UPDATE 2**

I concretize my question: why `double` memoized in `@external` between tests, but without stubbed methods?

Answer (score 0):

Because `let` creates a new double for each example.

Try running this spec with the newest (3.6) rspec, and you will get the following error:

```
1) App.bar calls func2
   Failure/Error: external.func2
     #<Double "ExternalObject"> was originally created in one example but has leaked into another example and can no longer be used. rspec-mocks' doubles are designed to only last for one example, and you need to create a new one in each example you wish to use it for.
```

This happens because of the memoization of the object on the class level.

When the first example gets ran, `let` creates the first double with first expectation and it gets memoized.

In the next example the `let` creates a new double and the expectation is set on that new double, however when the test code calls for the `described_class.external` it receives the first memoized test double and not the new one with the new expectation.

You can try see in the following example:

```
RSpec.describe App do
  let(:external) { double('ExternalObject', func1: 1, func2: 2) }

  before { allow(ExternalObject).to receive(:new).and_return(external) }

  describe '.foo' do
    it 'calls func1' do
      p external.object_id # => 70184943614340
      p described_class.external.object_id # => 70184943614340
      expect(external).to receive(:func1)

      described_class.foo
    end
  end

  describe '.bar' do
    it 'calls func2' do
      p external.object_id # => 70184942937140
      p described_class.external.object_id # => 70184943614340
      expect(external).to receive(:func2)

      described_class.bar
    end
  end
end
```